# Leave MySQL connection idle to be reused or connect on demand, what about classes?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, .net-4.0

I am currently working on a Desktop Application using winforms and .NET 4.0, I have downloaded the latest MySQL connector for .NET 4.0 but I have a few doubts of what would be the best way to go with it.

NOTE: Just want to point out this application is for personal use and will be running on my own server.

- My application is connected to a server but does not receive information at all the times, should I make on demand connections to MySQL to process the data received or should I leave an connection to MySQL open for as long as the application is open idling so it can be reused when data is received ?
- I have been looking around for some more recent documents in regards of using MySQL with c# but all I could found was tutorials dated from 2006 is there some good examples that are more recent that I could use as a reference (this is my first time using MySQL with c#) specially documents showing how to serialize/deserialize data using the DataTable stuff would be very welcome ?

  **I would be happy with some code examples of classes you guys often use to establish a connection or pull data from it.**
- Another question I was considering which is not so related to this is: When should I consider using a web API over direct MySQL connections with my application ?

Comment: in almost all cases, connections should be opened and closed as needed. Don't keep them open for long periods

Comment: @Mitch Wheat but wouldn't connecting over and over produce a bigger impact on performance ? What if i  get something to process now and every 30 seconds after for the next hour it does something it would be connecting and disconnecting for each of those wouldn't be more convenient to have it open ?

Comment: see my previous advice. Connections go back into a pool, and get reused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my view, you should open the connection at the beginning of a user action and close it at the end. This won't affect performance significantly because connecting is just as quick as doing a single query.

However, if you open/close a connection for each sub-operation, you can end up with poor performance. Be sure that you don't do that.

---

The main motivation for using a new connection each time, is that you can avoid the following classes of bugs:

- "Morning" bugs where the database has disappeared or disconnected after a while (or timeouts on stateful firewalls, etc)
- "Stale state" bugs where some previous action has left the connection in a "broken" state and causes the next action to fail or behave unexpectedly (e.g. "SET names koi8")

It is possible to reset a mysql connection by doing a mysql_change_user (If your API supports it), but this is almost the same as reconnecting (it just uses the same tcp connection).

Comment: +1 thanks for the reply, I was thinking of leaving it open for let's say 5 minutes and if no one uses it after that it would close or if some one uses it, it would remain for another 5 minutes, what do you think ? Would you happen to have any classes about how you often use your connection or any material to link me that is not paid and not too old ? once again thanks for the reply.